# Reading JSON data in c#, in XML Program

Tags: c#, xml, json, serialization, xml-serialization

Can some one help me in finding out this?

I wanted to read the below timestamp in the resultant JSON response (in BOLD).
I want to copy the value of t (first and second time in the response).

```
{"op":"&amp;","c":[{"type":"completion","cm":1254,"e":1},{"type":"completion","cm":27869,"e":1},{"type":"date","d":"&gt;=","t":**1426767000**},{"type":"date","d":"&lt;","t":**1458389400**}],"showc":[true,true,true,true]}
```

Here is my program code:

```
currentnode = matchquiz.SelectNodes("KEY[@name='availability']/VALUE")[0];
if (currentnode != null)
{
    mdle_availablefrom = currentnode.FirstChild.Value;
    if (mdle_availablefrom != "0")
    {
          //System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0);
          //dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(double.Parse(mdle_availablefrom)).ToLocalTime();
          //mdle_availablefrom = dtDateTime.ToString();
    }
    else
          mdle_availablefrom = string.Empty;
}
```

I have saved the response in "mdle_availablefrom", Now i want toread the values of both the t's in two different variables in the if block. 
Value of t(Time) is in double.

Comment: What is `matchquiz`, an `XmlDocument`? Something is missing here, how can JSON string on top relates to the codes below it, Can you pl be clear??

Comment: hi @har07. matchquiz is just a xml variable initialized, 
`XmlNode matchquiz = module.ParentNode;`

i have the JSON response in `mdle_availablefrom` and want to parse the json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create an object model that represents the JSON you can then use it as an object set and it's far more readable to other programmers using the code.

I recommend NewtonJSON :)

```
Deserialize by var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```